# How to avoid getting "unidentified developer" warning while running AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have created an AppleScript app. I removed `com.apple.quarantine` using `xattr` command. When I share the app with others through the Internet and they download and run it, they get a warning of "unidentified developer". How can they avoid getting such warnings and make the app working by double-clicking it?

Comment: Improve grammar and formatting. Add OSX tag

Comment: Thanks @StevePiercy

Answer (score 0):

The quarantine tag gets added each time the app is downloaded from the Internet.  Running `xattr` only removes the quarantine tag from the application on *your* computer.

In order for others to be able to run it without Gatekeeper alerting, *they* would have to first run `xattr -d -r` on the file to remove the quarantine flag that was added when *they* downloaded the application from the Internet.

Note that this is not the case when downloading a zipped application from the command line using something like `curl` or `wget`.  It mainly applies to items downloaded through a normal browser.